# Recreating local selinux contexts after OS Reinstallation

Tags: rhel, selinux

We have added a few specific contexts to our SELinux via the "semanage fcontext ..." command. The patterns are stored in /etc/selinux/targetd/contexts/files/file_contexts.local.

Assuming that we either wished to implement the same permissions on a different machine, or had to re-install the OS on this machine, is placing the file_contexts.local in the correct location sufficient? Are there any additional steps one would need to take to make SELinux process and use the file?

OS: RHEL 6.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to copying over the `/etc/selinux/targetd/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` file, you will also need to run the `restorecon` command on the directories and files referenced within `/etc/selinux/targetd/contexts/files/file_contexts.local`.

A simple way to do this (while also setting the SELinux context for all files in the system referenced by `/etc/selinux/targetd/contexts/files/file_contexts` -- the SELinux defaults) would be to run the following command:

```
$ sudo restorecon -R /
```

***Note***: the `-R` flag means recurse into subdirectories and files, thus restoring context for all files on the system as defined in the `file_context` and `file_context.local` files.

**EDIT:** As sourcejedi has wisely pointed out in the comments. Running `restorecon` on the whole filesystem may attempt to change labels on filesystems that do not support it (i.e. mounted drives, etc.). You may use the `fixfiles restore` command to avoid this issue.

From the `fixfiles` man page:

```
By default it will relabel all mounted ext2, ext3, xfs and jfs file systems as 
long as they do not have a security context mount option. The file 
/etc/selinux/fixfiles_exclude_dirs can contain a list of directories 
excluded from relabeling.
```

You may also use `fixfiles onboot` which will relabel on the next reboot.

Similarly, `touch /.autorelabel && reboot` will relabel files during the reboot/

Comment: Using `fixfiles restore` instead would avoid trying to change labels on filesystems which do not support it, e.g. avoiding a flood of error messages on /boot/efi.  Even better might be `touch /.autorelabel && reboot`.  This will minimize problems e.g. if you have any daemons running with the "wrong" label.